# Finding first iteration of a string in a datatable in R

Tags: r, datatable

I am pretty new to R so I was trying to figure out how can I do this better. I have a data table that consist of two columns, (Day and Sleepstatus). How can I find the first iteration of Sleeping and Awake based on the column day and mutate another column to indicate when the person start sleep (1st row of sleeping) and stop sleep (1st row of awake). The rest of the duration of sleeping, the column should show N.A.

| Day | SleepStatus |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sleeping |
| 1 | Sleeping |
| 1 | Sleeping |
| 1 | Awake |
| 2 | Sleeping |
| 2 | Sleeping |
| 2 | Sleeping |
| 2 | Awake |

Desired Output

| Day | SleepStatus | Final Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sleeping | Start Sleep |
| 1 | Sleeping | NA |
| 1 | Sleeping | Stop Sleep |
| 1 | Awake | NA |
| 2 | Sleeping | Start Sleep |
| 2 | Sleeping | NA |
| 2 | Sleeping | Stop Sleep |
| 2 | Awake | NA |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one potential solution:

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table::data.table(
          Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
  SleepStatus = c("Sleeping","Sleeping","Sleeping",
                  "Awake","Sleeping","Sleeping","Sleeping","Awake")
)

dt[, `Final Status` := {ifelse(
  cumsum(SleepStatus != "Sleeping") != shift(cumsum(SleepStatus != "Sleeping"), fill = 0, type = "lag"),
  "Stop Sleep", "Start Sleep")}]
dt[, `Final Status` := {ifelse(
  `Final Status` == shift(`Final Status`, fill = "NA", type = "lag"),
  NA, `Final Status`)}]
dt
#>    Day SleepStatus Final Status
#> 1:   1    Sleeping  Start Sleep
#> 2:   1    Sleeping         <NA>
#> 3:   1    Sleeping         <NA>
#> 4:   1       Awake   Stop Sleep
#> 5:   2    Sleeping  Start Sleep
#> 6:   2    Sleeping         <NA>
#> 7:   2    Sleeping         <NA>
#> 8:   2       Awake   Stop Sleep
```

---

The code makes a lot more sense if you break it down into smaller chunks. I've done this with tidyverse functions below, as I feel it's easier to understand, but I can change it to data.table syntax if you would like me to.

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table::data.table(
          Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
  SleepStatus = c("Sleeping","Sleeping","Sleeping",
                  "Awake","Sleeping","Sleeping","Sleeping","Awake")
)

library(tidyverse)
df <- as.data.frame(dt)

# When the Sleepstatus is not "Sleeping", increment the variable by one
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(Sleeping = cumsum(SleepStatus != "Sleeping"))
df2
#>   Day SleepStatus Sleeping
#> 1   1    Sleeping        0
#> 2   1    Sleeping        0
#> 3   1    Sleeping        0
#> 4   1       Awake        1
#> 5   2    Sleeping        1
#> 6   2    Sleeping        1
#> 7   2    Sleeping        1
#> 8   2       Awake        2

# If the previous value in "Sleeping" is different to the current value,
# add the "stop sleeping" flag (i.e. show when "Sleeping" changes)
df3 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(Sleep_label = ifelse(Sleeping != lag(Sleeping, default = 0), "Stop sleeping", "Start sleeping"))
df3
#>   Day SleepStatus Sleeping    Sleep_label
#> 1   1    Sleeping        0 Start sleeping
#> 2   1    Sleeping        0 Start sleeping
#> 3   1    Sleeping        0 Start sleeping
#> 4   1       Awake        1  Stop sleeping
#> 5   2    Sleeping        1 Start sleeping
#> 6   2    Sleeping        1 Start sleeping
#> 7   2    Sleeping        1 Start sleeping
#> 8   2       Awake        2  Stop sleeping

# Then, if the value in Sleep_label is equal to the previous label,
# change it to NA
df4 <- df3 %>%
  mutate(Final_status = ifelse(Sleep_label == lag(Sleep_label, default = "NA"), NA, Sleep_label))
df4
#>   Day SleepStatus Sleeping    Sleep_label   Final_status
#> 1   1    Sleeping        0 Start sleeping Start sleeping
#> 2   1    Sleeping        0 Start sleeping           <NA>
#> 3   1    Sleeping        0 Start sleeping           <NA>
#> 4   1       Awake        1  Stop sleeping  Stop sleeping
#> 5   2    Sleeping        1 Start sleeping Start sleeping
#> 6   2    Sleeping        1 Start sleeping           <NA>
#> 7   2    Sleeping        1 Start sleeping           <NA>
#> 8   2       Awake        2  Stop sleeping  Stop sleeping
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Does that make sense? Or did I just make things more confusing?

Comment: it works! but can you slightly explain how this code is run? I do have another variables that I need to search for the first and last iteration so I would like to understand how this code works

Comment: yes I get it! But what if I slightly change the value which means that the first row instead of sleeping is awake. And that the start sleep will only start from the first sleeping and will not show stop sleep at the first row? How will the code change? This code seems to suggest if the first row is not sleeping, I will insert a stop sleep instead of finding the first sleeping variable

Comment: for the code, is it possible to edit the stop sleeping on the last sleeping instead of awake?

Answer (score 1):

in Base R you could do the following:

```
x <- dt$SleepStatus
is.na(x) <- -cumsum(c(1,head(rle(x)$lengths,-1)))
dt$final_status <- c(Sleeping = 'Start Sleep', Awake = 'Stop Sleep')[x]
dt

  Day SleepStatus final_status
1   1    Sleeping  Start Sleep
2   1    Sleeping         <NA>
3   1    Sleeping         <NA>
4   1       Awake   Stop Sleep
5   2    Sleeping  Start Sleep
6   2    Sleeping         <NA>
7   2    Sleeping         <NA>
8   2       Awake   Stop Sleep
```

Comment: is it possible to explain your code? can I edit the code to find out the last Sleeping before it change status to Awake?

Comment: @JordanIatro the code uses `Run Length Encoding` (rle) to determine the sleeping/awake pattern. Then for each Sleeping not in the RLE, it should be turned to NA because its continued sleeping ie so i have `-` to indicate those that need to be turned to NA. Then i just replace the remaining Sleepint to Start Sleep and Awake to Stop Sleep.

Comment: @JordanIatro to find the last sleeping, just do `max(which(df$final_status =="Sleeping"))` or probably you are looking for `max(which (df$SleepStatus=="Sleeping"))`

Comment: what I meant was in the different day, to locate the last sleeping as Stop Sleep instead of Awake. Is it possible to do so with the code?

Comment: @JordanIatro i dont understand your question, you will have to post your expected output then i can see what you mean

Comment: i edited the output, what I meant was to look for the last iteration to end the "status" instead of the change in iteration.